# `add_route': Invalid route name, already in use: 'new_user_session' (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, routes, precompile

I am having trouble getting my app to run in production via Heroku. It is a fully working application in development.

I researched this question on SO but many of the solutions were because of a duplicate `devise_for` in their `routes.rb`. My app does not have this issue, and I have had difficulty in finding out where this duplication is occurring.

This is the full error message:

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:557:in `add_route': Invalid route name, already in use: 'new_user_session'  (ArgumentError)
You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option,  or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming. For the latter, you can restrict the routes created with `resources` as explained here: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created
```

This is my current `routes.rb` file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }

get 'items/create'

get  'welcome/index'

get  'about' => 'welcome#about'

get  'brandon' => 'welcome#brandon'

root 'welcome#index'

resources :users, only: [:index, :show] do
  resources :items
 end

end
```

I have updated my gems, dropped the database and re-migrated it to no effect.

Comment: Possibly unrelated but your first two GET routes aren't showing which controller and action to be directed to, also try placing your root just below the devise_for route.

Answer (score 0):

```
#config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :items, only: [:new, :create], path_names: { new: "create" }    
  resources :welcome, path: "", only: :index do #-> url.com/
     collection do
        get :about   #-> url.com/about
        get :brandon #-> url.com/brandon
     end
  end

  resources :users, only: [:index, :show] do #-> there may be a conflict with "/users/" as devise also uses "/users/" path
     resources :items #-> url.com/users/:user_id/items
  end

  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'registrations' }

  root "welcome#index"
end
```

I'll delete this if it doesn't work; you either have a problem with the "naked" declarations you're making (always try and scope your routes around [`resources`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default)), or you have a conflicting file in your production environment.

Comment: Hi Rich - thanks for the comment! I tried using your routes set up, but I got the same error again. However I do thank you for the notice on setting up routes - the 'naked declarations' is simply how I began learning how to write routes. This way is certainly much clearer :)

Answer (score 0):

I went into similar situation.
The use of **as** option of devise_for solved for me.

```
devise_for :users, as: "unique_prefix", :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
```